# How do I find an optimal solution to the 24 puzzle in a timely manner?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, heuristics

**Problem:**

Compute an optimal solution to a random 24 (5x5) [sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle) in less than 5 seconds (on the average computer).

**What I've tried:**

Using the [IDA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*) algorithm with Manhattan distance/Linear conflict as a heuristic as explained [here](https://algorithmsinsight.wordpress.com/graph-theory-2/a-star-in-general/implementing-a-star-to-solve-n-puzzle/), my Java implementation can solve a 4x4 (15) puzzle in less than 2 seconds.

Running the same implementation on a 5x5 (24) puzzle produces the solution's path after 5 minutes.

I was thinking that I could reduce the search space, and thus reduce execution time, by first solving the top row and the left column, and then continue by solving the remaining 4x4 box. This has proved to be difficult, as I cannot think of/design a heuristic that can make IDA* solve the top and left parts in a timely manner.

Comment: In the optimization world few people develop in Java, C++ is a better option

Comment: Have a had a look to Pattern Databases?

Comment: @FrankS101 I just tried pattern databases, and.. they are also really slow at finding the optimal solution

Answer (score 2):

In AI book by russel and norvig it is mentioned that 5x5 sliding puzzle have such an  huge state space that it can take hours to slove by even best AI search algorithms. (page 71, 3rd edition)